# AsyncStorage.setItem() not working as expected

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Very simple code, I am trying to add a userToken to a native device's async storage from React Native. However, no matter what value I put into the `AsyncStorage.setItem()`, when I console.log the result, I just get this weird object... `{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}`

The code is very straightforward,

```
async function setTokenAsyncAndRegular(token){
 setToken(token)
 console.log("Setting async to...", token)
 return await AsyncStorage.setItem('@token', token)
}

// Takes the resolved promise from LOGIN
const parseResolvedData = async (userObj) => {
 setFailedLogin(false)
 setFailedSignup(false)
 await setTokenAsyncAndRegular(userObj.loginUser.token)
 console.log("Async says...", AsyncStorage.getItem('@token'))
}
```

And the console gives me the following logs when I run the code...

```
 LOG  Setting async to... U2FsdGVkX1+Av7fvH++UIDCDskS+fkCV0WP8SM0Fo+m1uGLavgASvPpu0FlovGplgHEggVp19ukSNEXuLiZYn2BkpS3BavfoVmv7uSaO254=
 LOG  Async says... {"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
```

Comment: You need to await `AsyncStorage.getItem`, it's an async call.  The object you're logging out is a pending promise.

Comment: Shouldn't the `await` calls solve that? I am unsure what else to try as I've also attempted using `.then()` blocks to no success

Comment: you wrote: `console.log("Async says...", AsyncStorage.getItem('@token'))`.  This call is not awaited.  It should be `console.log("Async says...", await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token'))`

Comment: Like @Abe said, on the console.log, you need to await for the `getItem`, like you did for the `setItem`